# Evaluation of Fourier series $\sum_{n=1,3,5...} \left[\frac{1}{n}\text{e}^{-\frac{n \pi x}{a}} \text{sin}(\frac{n \pi y}{a}) \right]$

Tags: fourier-series, electromagnetism, parsevals-identity

I was studying electromagnetism and followed 'Introduction to Electromagnetism' by David Griffiths. During his derivation of the solution to Laplace's equation in ch. 3.3, he derives the equation $$V(x,y)=\frac{4 V_0}{\pi} \sum_{n=1,3,5...} \left[\frac{1}{n}\text{e}^{-\frac{n \pi x}{a}} \text{sin}\left(\frac{n \pi y}{a}\right) \right].$$

It is stated that the infinite series can be summed explicitly and the complete expression evaluates to $V(x,y)=\frac{2 V_0}{\pi} \text{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{sin}(\frac{\pi y}{a})}{\text{sinh}(\frac{\pi x}{a})}\right)$, and I was wondering how he derives this results. We obviously have to determine the convergence of the series, and I assume we can use Parseval's theorem, but some help would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely Rasmus

Comment: Your sum, not including the constant, is the imaginary part of $$f(z)=\sum_{n\text{ odd}}\frac{z^n}{n}$$ where $z=e^{\pi(-x+yi)/a}.$ But the derivative of $f$ is $\frac1{1-z^2}.$ So you can use partial fractions to get a formula for $f$ as $\frac12\log\frac{1+z}{1-z}.$

Comment: Hello Thomas

Thank you for your brilliant answer. Just to state the equation explicitly, we have $\text{Im}\left(\sum_{\text{n odd}}\frac{\text{e}^{-n \pi x/a}\text{e}^{n i y \pi/a}}{n}\right)=\sum_{\text{n odd}}\frac{\text{e}^{-\pi n x/a} sin(y \pi n/a)}{n}=\sum_{\text{n odd}}\frac{z^n}{n}$ using Euler.

Thus we have to determine $\frac{1}{2}\text{Im}\left[\text{log}(\frac{1+z}{1-z})\right]$. How do I evaluate the imaginary part of this complex logarithm?

Comment: I know that Im[log(z)]=arg(z)=arg(a+ib)=tan^(-1)(b/a) if a>0, but how do I convert log[(1+z)/(1-z)] to the form log(a+ib)?

Comment: Okay, I have now completely solved the problem. Thank you.